# not getting self.start_scene in lpthw ex42

Tags: python

I am struggling with lpthw. Can somebody  explain why it is self.start_scene and not just start_scene in the highlited portion of below code.Full code here https://github.com/krmaxwell/lpthw/blob/master/ex43/ex43.py

```
class Map(object):
    scenes = {
              'central_corridor': CentralCorridor(),
              'laser_weapon_armory': LaserWeaponArmory(),
              'the_bridge': TheBridge(),
              'escape_pod': EscapePod(),
              'death': Death(),
              'finished': Finish()
    }

    def __init__(self, start_scene):
        self.start_scene = start_scene
        print("start_scene in __init__", self.start_scene)

    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        print("start_scene in next_scene")
        val = Map.scenes.get(scene_name)
        print("next_scene returns", val)
        return val

    def opening_scene(self):
        return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)


a_map = Map('central_corridor')
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

Comment: FYI: https://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints

Comment: If you are referring to this line `print("start_scene in __init__", self.start_scene)`, there is no reason. Both `self.start_scene` and `start_scene` refer to the same object at that moment.